# Delete photos from WhatsApp backup

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, sync

I had recently painstakingly deleted lot of unwanted WhatsApp photos from my gallery to save storage space. But unfortunately WhatsApp has again restored all those photos (probably from backup). How do I say to WhatsApp that locally deleted photos should also be deleted in backup also?

Comment: Can I delete backup from Google Drive and rebackup from local storage? So that deleted images are permanently deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the photos/videos you don't want. Then create a new chat backup, overwritting the old one that should fix it. [image: chat backup]
Might not resolve the longer term issue though.

Comment: What do you mean by 'might not resolve the longer term issue'?